# Loop on indexes of an array

Tags: perl

I need to extract each character in a string and show the position in an index.

My coding is :

```
my $seq2 = substr ($seq, $i, 1);
my @a = ("$seq2");
foreach my $i (0.. $#a)
{
    print "$i  - $a[$i]";
}
```

But it shows all the character at an index position 0

Comment: What's `$seq2` in your example?

Comment: The variable where each character is extracted and stored. The earlier line is a typo. It should be $seq2 = substr  ($seq, $i, 1);

Comment: If there is a typo in your code, I recommend you [edit] it.

Comment: ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`! You're using `$i` before you declare and assign to it!

Comment: `@a` only has one element! `foreach my $i (0.. $#a)` is this the same as `foreach my $i (0)`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the string into a list of its characters and assign that to an array

```
my @chars = split //, $string;
```

and then iterate over the array's index, `foreach my $i (0..$#chars)`, as you seem to want to.

However, your use of [substr](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) in this context doesn't make sense. It returns the single character at a given position `$i` and then `@a` contains a single element.

If you wanted to use `substr` it would have to be in a loop in which `$i` iterates from `0` to string's length `-1`, so to extract each character.  This would be very inefficient though, involving a call to `substr` for every character.

---

Using regular expressions and [pos](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $string = q(abcdefg); 

while ($string =~ /(.)/g) { say "$1: ", pos $string }
```

Here `.` matches any character while `/g` modifier makes it continue matching from that position in the next iteration, thus scanning the string character by character.  Since each match is captured by `()` it is available in `$1`. The `pos` "*Returns the offset of where the last `m//g` search left off* ..."

Comment: I need to extract each character from a string and then store it in an array, so that i would get the position of each character. That why I used substr

Comment: @user9255546 OK, I thought so. But then `substr` should be in a loop, so the extract _every_ character, as I explain. (And that is very inefficient in comparison with other approaches.)   Then you can also `push` them onto an array inside that loop. But that is done with `split` in one statement, and then you can iterate over index.

Comment: I used the way you suggested and it worked petfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: @user9255546 I added a basic explanation of the regex.